# ¿Como recorrer un conjunto de JLabel?

Tags: java, java-swing

primero doy una breve descripción de lo que estoy haciendo, tengo dos frame, uno donde lleno una matriz de **Espectador** (clase) y otro donde tengo los asientos de un cine en el que cada cuadrito es un label con icono, las posiciones de la **matriz** representa los asientos.
Ahora para cambiar los label de color necesito ayuda para recorrer el conjunto de label ya que necesito editar su icon cuando este ocupado el asiento (osea que la matriz[x][y] tenga un Espectador.
Puedo hacerlo con un if el problema es que son 72 label y es mucho código, osea esta mal.
Quisiera saber como recorrer los Jlabel para hacer todo con un solo if, si tienen otra solución también agradezco la ayuda; adjunto código e imagenes al final.

```
//La condición para que cambie el icono a rojo, aqui lo hago manual sin un ciclo.                 
if(matriz[0][0]!=null){
silla.jLabel1.setIcon(newjavax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenens/rojo.png")));
}
```

Interfaz al comienzo.

[image: Asientos al comienzo]

Lo que deberia hacer al usar el if y encontrar una posición de matriz llena.
[image: Despues de llenar]

Comment: Lo que necesitas son dos bucles anidados. Con uno recorres las filas y con el otro las columnas de tu matriz.

Comment: @E.Betanzos Puedo recorrer toda la matriz con el bucle pero ¿como le digo que Jlabel cambiar?

Comment: Estaba asumiendo que tu matriz contenía los jLabes, ej. `JLabe[][] matriz = ...`

Comment: @E.Betanzos Pense en esa solución pero no sé como hacer la matriz con los JLabel que tengo, ¿habría que crearlos manual y añadirlos? porque es un problema para luego ubicarlos en el frame.

Comment: Si ya tienes las 72 variables solo debes hacer algo como esto: `matriz[0][0] = jLabel1;`. Y así con las 72 según su posición.

Answer (score 0):

Pudieras tener una clase Asiento:

```
public class Asiento {
  private JLabel label; //yo aquí usaría mejor un JButton porque además de que
                        //se le puede poner un icono también puedes escuchar cuando
                        //el usuario seleccione este asiento y tomar acción

  private boolean ocupado;
  private int fila;
  private int columna;

  public void setOcupado(boolean ocupado) {
      if (ocupado)  {
        //le pones el icono rojo
      }
      else {
         //le pones el icono verde
      }
  }
}
```

En el constructor puedes definir de una vez el icono dependiendo si está o no ocupado.

Respecto a como pasar las 72 JLabels que definiste, yo quizás las crearía en un ciclo, y una vez creadas las posicionaría en el layout que tengas. Aunque buscaría la forma de que ese mismo ciclo pudiera ponerlas en el layout y no hacerlo manualmente.

Notese que ahora tu matriz sería de Asientos.